# Why does the message print twice?

Tags: c, while-loop

I am creating a simple Tic Tac Toe for C, and here is a particular function which I am having a problem with.  This is supposed to let the user select 'X' or 'O', and for the most art it works.  However, if I enter a wrong symbol, it prints the statement: 
"Invalid symbol, please re-enter: " twice.

Why and **how** can I fix this?

```
char assign(void)                                 
{
      char user;

      printf("Would you like to be X or O (Enter your choice): ");
      user=getchar();
      while(user != 'X' && user != 'x' && user != 'O' && user != 'o')
      {
             printf("Invalid symbol, please re-enter: ");  
             user=getchar();
      }
      if(user == 'O' || user == 'o')        return('O');
      else if(user == 'X' || user == 'x')   return('X');     
}
```

Comment: It probably catches the "\n" character when you hit enter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using getchar() in a while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549701/using-getchar-in-a-while-loop).  There was also [`while` loops duplicates `printf()` two times before getting to character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892383/while-loops-duplicates-printf-two-times-before-getting-to-getchar) earlier today.  There are likely to be others, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you use `getchar` it returns the next character, but leaves the newline in the input buffer. So the next `getchar` returns that newline.

You should also be careful because `getchar` actually returns an `int` and not a `char`.

You can solve this either by another `getchar`, or use `scanf` like this:

```
scanf("%c ", &user);
```

Note the space after the `c` in the above format, it tells `scanf` to read and disregard trailing whitespace.

You could also read a line with e.g. `fgets` and then use a simple `sscanf` on that line, then no extra space is needed.

Comment: But better one is use `int` `user`

Comment: what do you mean use another getchar()? But thanks I will accept it as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @C_Beginner_Learner One `getchar` to get the character you want, and one to get (and throw away) the newline.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, it works now, except that it prints a weird 'u' symbol once I re-enter the valid symbol.

Comment: The space after the `%c` is probably not a good idea; `scanf()` doesn't stop looking for input until you've typed another non-white space character.  Using `" %c"` (space before) reads any white space, such as a newline leftover from the previous input line, and then returns the first character that isn't white space.

Answer (score 4):

The problem cause is related to the newline charachter

use `scanf()` in this way instead of using `getchar()`

```
scanf(" %c", &user);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! This is better than the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could fix it like this for example:

```
char assign(void)
{
      char user;
      char throwaway_newline;

      printf("Would you like to be X or O (Enter your choice): ");
      user=getchar();
      throwaway_newline = getchar();
      while(user != 'X' && user != 'x' && user != 'O' && user != 'o')
      {
             printf("Invalid symbol, please re-enter: ");  
             user=getchar();
             throwaway_newline = getchar();
      }
      if(user == 'O' || user == 'o')        return('O');
      else if(user == 'X' || user == 'x')   return('X');     
}
```

Comment: Once I do this, it doesn't repeat lines, but, it prints a weird 'u' symbol once I re-enter the valid symbol (FYI I added a break statement after `throwaway_newline = getchar();`

Comment: @C_Beginner_Learner: This is not a super great fix, to be honest (e.g. you cannot enter more than one symbol) I am not sure where your 'u' characters comes from.

Comment: If a `break` is added in the loop and the character is incorrect, then you fall out of the bottom of the function without actually returning a value, so you might get `u` as the garbage non-returned value.  The `break` (added by @C_Beginner_Learner) is inappropriate.  The unchecked use of `getchar()` could cause problems; if you get EOF, you have an infinite loop.  And the `else if` clause would probably be better as plain `else` or even without the `else`:  `if (user == 'O' || user == 'o') return('O'); return('X');`.

Comment: but without the break, the statement "Invalid symbol, please re-enter:" continously repeats after entering symbols (as you said an infinite loop).  So what can I do? @JonathanLeffler (besides changing the `else if` to else)

Comment: You can drive this code into a loop by typing just newline at the first response, or by typing blank and `o` (say) plus newline.  The second iteration reads the newline into `user`, and then waits for more input.  I think the simplest solution is to use `while (scanf(" %c", &user) == 1 && user != 'X' && user != 'x' && user != 'O' && user != 'o') { printf("Invalid symbol. Please re-enter O or X: ");` to read the character, and a loop `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` afterwards to read up to and including the newline (also taking care of EOF).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Why you have used `scanf(" %c", &user) == 1` in while? Is this for checking that either user inputs a char or not or something else?

Comment: @haccks: With the `%c` format, it mainly detects EOF (when `scanf()` returns EOF) and handles that appropriately.  With other formats, such as `%d` to read an integer, it detects both EOF and a complete mismatch, such as a letter, in the input.  If you are looking for a number and the next character is a letter, `scanf()` will return 0 items converted.  If you don't handle this, you can end up with an infinite loop (not so easily with `%c`).  Input (in particular) requires constant care — always consider EOF and error conditions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; OK. I think `scanf(" %c", &user)` also return `1` if EOF is encountered, isn't it?

Comment: @haccks: No...go read the specification of [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have a newline in your input buffer.

When you press a character which is not [xX] and not [oO] and follow it with a newline. `getchar` actually gets to see 2 characters(the newline and the invalid character)

You may want to use `fgets` instead of relying on character input and ignoring newlines with 2 getchar() calls everytime.